# Diagnostics.StopWatch time lag in XP but not Win7

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, timing, stopwatch

ETA: Using Environment.TickCount does not present the same problem.
ETA2: I should add that I don't actually use the Forms.Timer in my app - as this would 
negate the use of a high frequency timer. I've used it here to simplify the code.

ETA3: I've published a workaround as an answer below.

I'm having problems with the StopWatch class that I'm observing on a laptop with XP but not a different laptop with Win7. Here's the test code:

```
Public Class FormTest
    Inherits Form

    Private WithEvents Timer1 As System.Windows.Forms.Timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Private sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Timer1.Interval = 1
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnClick(e)
        Me.sw.Start()
        Me.Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Me.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString
        Me.Update()
    End Sub

End Class
```

On windows 7, checking the ellapsed milliseconds every second, I get something like:
0, 1010, 2030, 3005 ...
On XP, I get something like: 0, 200, 306, 390, 512, ...

That is, it is way off. We're not talking about milliseconds.
It's nothing to do with whether the timer is high resolution, as that reports as true. As 
far as I know it's nothing to do with processor affinity as I've tried setting that to each of the 2 processors.

As I say, I think this is to do with XP, but it could be to do with the different cores - both laptops are, however, intel.

Comment: Are you using two laptops or dual booting on a single laptop?

Comment: I don't see where you set the interval vor your `Timer1` timer?

Comment: Dammit, never clean up code after pasting!. I've added the part back in. The interval is 1, which, with the Forms.Timer, equates to about 30 times a second I think.

Comment: @Mike It's two different laptops

Comment: The timer interval accuracy is constrained by hardware and windows thread scheduling. It might be quite different between two machines with different OS.

Comment: @driis Are you talking about a few milliseconds differences? If I leave it running for 10 seconds, on XP I would see ellapsed milliseconds of around 2 seconds. I don't know if it helps, but using Environment.TickCount does not have the same issue.

Comment: Can whoever down-voted the question please add a comment to explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Do you set the interval of the timer anywhere?

To me it looks like they are running with different intervals. The Win7 is roughly fired every second. The XP one looks like it could be fired every 100ms (with a few sample points missed - it's hard to read things that fast).

I can't find any documentation on the default timer interval. If it is undocumented, it could have been changed between OS and .NET framework versions between your machines.

Comment: Hi, the Win7 timer is not firing every second, I just make a note of the Form text every second.

Comment: The timer has some default value, it might be different between the OS'es. If it is a second on Win7, you will only get updates each second. Also, "make a note every second" seems like a very non-scientific way to go about this.

Comment: I saw in the comments above that I'd removed a part of the code by mistake; Me.Timer1.Interval = 1.

Comment: @Anders - I can now see why you thought is was firing every second as I'd removed part of the code by mistake. Me.Timer1.Interval = 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by using the *timeGetTime* method instead. The following code is 
basically the *Diagnostics.StopWatch* class but with the *QueryPerformanceCounter* call replaced with *timeGetTime*.

I haven't fully tested it yet* but, from what I've read, I should be able to make a call to 
*TimeBeginPeriod(1)* to achieve resolution in line with the framework stopwatch.

(*If have fully tested it now and it does achieve millisecond accuracy).

If anyone can tell me how to make QueryPerformanceCounter work for XP (if indeed XP is the problem), or detect if there is a problem, I'll un-mark this and mark yours as the answer.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Friend Class StopWatch

    Private Elapsed As Integer
    Private StartTimeStamp As Integer

    Public Sub Start()
        If Not Me._IsRunning Then
            Me.StartTimeStamp = StopWatch.timeGetTime
            Me._IsRunning = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub [Stop]()
        If Me.isRunning Then
            Me.Elapsed = (Me.Elapsed + (StopWatch.timeGetTime - Me.StartTimeStamp))
            Me._IsRunning = False
            If (Me.Elapsed < 0) Then
                Me.Elapsed = 0
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Reset()
        Me.Elapsed = 0
        Me._IsRunning = False
        Me.StartTimeStamp = 0
    End Sub

    Private _IsRunning As Boolean
    Public ReadOnly Property IsRunning() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._IsRunning
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ElapsedMilliseconds() As Integer
        Get
            Dim elapsed = Me.Elapsed
            If Me._IsRunning Then
                elapsed = (elapsed + (StopWatch.timeGetTime - Me.StartTimeStamp))
            End If
            Return elapsed
        End Get
    End Property

    <DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function timeGetTime() As Integer
    End Function

End Class
```